# Какую лучше архитектуру использовать для вычислений на GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, opencl

Необходимо перенести вычисления с `CPU` на `GPU`. Начал гуглить про это всё, в итоге есть 2 похожие архитектуры - `CUDA` от `Nvidia` и `OpenCL` от `AMD`, второе можно и на `Nvidia` использовать. Вроде бы пишут, что видеокарты на AMD больше заточены под вычисления и быстрее на 30-40%.

У кого был опыт программирования на подобном. Можете прояснить пожалуйста, что лучше выбрать для себя?

Программу пишу на C#, но как понял, класс вычислений придется писать на C++ и подключать библиотеку к своей программе.

Comment: исходя из этой [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/96122/). CUDA быстрее на несколько десятков гигафлопсов

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да, я тоже читал эту статью, но это 8 лет назад было и openCL только развивалось тогда.

Comment: У вас путаница. CUDA - это вычислительная платформа от NVIDIA, OpenCL - это фреймворк для паралельных вычислений, который может быть использован в том числе и на CUDA GPU от NVIDIA. Но это все - дело десятое, главное - это качественно распараллелить вычислительные задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Занимаюсь сложными гидродинамическими расчётами на GPU уже давно - OpenCL. По производительности вычислений **float** карты NVidia всегда опережают AMD с аналогичным количеством и частотой потоковых процессоров. Процентов на 30-50.
От использования **double** лучше по возможности уходить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А почему именно от использования `double` лучше уходить? Вопрос только в памяти?

Comment: Работа с double переменными на игровых видеокартах в 4-6 раз медленнее, чем с обычными float (проверял). Особенно на NVidia. На проф. видеокартах (для расчётов) это соотношение примерно 3. В остальных смыслах от проф. видеокарт толку нет - они уступают игровым, а по цене втрое дороже.

Comment: Странно, хорошо, я проверю тоже тогда с `double` и `float`. Просто у меня везде данные `double` именно. Отпишусь, как проверю. Спасибо

Comment: Владимир, вы в файле cl добавляли какие-нибудь библиотеки с помощью `include`?

Comment: Пробовал подключать СВОИ биб-ки с пом-ю Include: получается. НО! Этот Include коварный: после 1-й успешной компиляции видео-драйвером, откомпилированная библиотека где-то сохраняется в памяти. Потом (при след.запуске) если в текст её файла *.cpp вносить изменения (ошибки даже), это не сказывается. Обхожусь без Include. Если у меня какой-то Kernel содержит осн-ой файл MyKernel.cpp, и файлы библиотек Lib1.cpp, Lib2.cpp...и т.д., то я их (Lib1.cpp + Lib2.cpp + MyKernel.cpp) на хосте просто объединяю в одну длинную строку, а её уже передаю на компиляцию видео-драйверу - clCreateProgramWithSource.

Comment: Вот да, я тоже слышал про такое и пытался найти адекватный пример, но безуспешно. Если вам не сложно, можете описать пожалуйста простейший пример, как это можно сделать? Например, чтобы у kernel была подключена библиотека с одной лишь функцией `printf("Hello World");` И еще один вопрос, но я его пока сам ищу, как можно реализовать генератор случайных чисел в Kernel? Я знаю, есть библиотеки. Но это уже для OpenCl 2.0 на C++. У вас был опыт с подобным?